# disable column store in azure sql dataware house

Tags: azure, databricks, columnstore, sql-data-warehouse

I am writing a dataframe from Azure Databricks onto a sql dataware house with

```
res.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
```

with this I am getting an error `Column &apos;username&apos; has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index.`

How can I either eliminate the column store completely, or change the data type of the columns to fit in  the column store?

I have a few columns that will be considered as integer and some that will be varchar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this option clause to your write statement. It takes the place of the with() clause of the CREATE TABLE (AS) statement:

```
.option ("tableOptions","heap,distribution=MY_DISTRIBUTION")
```

Reference is here:

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html

Choose a value for MY_DISTRIBUTION based on the following guidance:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-distribute

Comment: Hi thanks a lot!. I tried adding `.option ("tableOptions","heap,distribution=HASH(rowno)") \` where rowno is int. I still get the same error as earlier referencing the same column. Is this syntax incorrect?

Comment: Did you drop the table first? I think you're inserting into the previously created table. You should also be able to use the .mode (SaveMode.Overwrite) clause.

Comment: I actualy tried creating a new table with a different name. At the moment there is no table created in the database with the name. The code looks like this now  _res.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table1) \
    .option ("tableOptions","heap, distribution=HASH(rowno)") \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()_

Comment: Is there a reason you're using .format("jdbc")? It should be .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw"). Take a close look at the examples in the Reference link that I posted above :)

Comment: hey yes that was the issue there. When i changed it, its loading data now. Thank you very much! the code finally is res.write \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
    .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "True") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table1) \
    .option("tableOptions","heap,distribution=HASH(rownum)") \
    .option("tempdir", tempDir) \
    .save()